# Generate an Arff File for Weka

Tags: java, weka, text-classification, arff

Hye there I am new to this work and I am getting confused after searching about how to get through it!
Actually i want to create a sparse ARFF file for weka for text classification! I have been searching online how to get start with it. My requirement is to generate a sparse arff file that should be compatible with the weka!
The outline for the arff should be like:

```
 @relation myrelation
 @attribute att0 numeric
 @attribute att1 numeric
 @data
 {0,1,4,5 , A}
 {0,5,2,,1 B}
```

Such that I have some strings and then a class
suppose my data set is as follow:

```
 string is a string A
 Hello a string B
 Another is string C
 .
 .
 .
```

first comes the string and then the class as A,B or C...
So what i want is to convert my dataset into above mentioned sparse arff format.
Can somebody give me a direction how can i do it? please
I want to do it in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Weka's StringToWordVector filter to convert the text into a word vector (but not necessarily a sparse matrix). Take a look at my [tutorial](http://youtu.be/jSZ9jQy1sfE) on this.

Comment: sir can you provide some link other than this youtube link thanks

Comment: You can learn by simply watching tutorials some times. Try it. I am not an English either.

Comment: Sir Rushdi Shams thanks for the tutorial you helped me lot and solved my problem thanks a lot may God Bless you Ameen

Comment: Good to know that. Thank you. Ameen.